# Unexpected Type errors

Tags: java

I'm getting two small unexpected type errors which I'm having trouble trying to solve.

The errors occur at:

```
swapped.charAt(temp1) = str.charAt(temp2);
swapped.charAt(temp2) = temp1;
```

Any advice?

```
public class SwapLetters
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String str = new String(args[0]);
        String swapped = str;

        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

        System.out.println("Enter a position to swap: ");

        int Swap1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        System.out.println("Enter a second position to swap: ");

        int Swap2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        char temp1 = str.charAt(Swap1);
        char temp2 = str.charAt(Swap2);

        swapped.charAt(temp1) = str.charAt(temp2);
        swapped.charAt(temp2) = temp1;

        System.out.println("Original String = " + str);
        System.out.println("Swapped String = " + swapped);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting

Comment: Did you read what the compiler has to say?

Comment: Good ole lside vs rside

Comment: SwapLetters.java:23: error: unexpected type
                swapped.charAt(temp1) = str.charAt(temp2);

Comment: You cannot assign `charAt(int index)`...

Comment: You can only assign into a variable. `String.charAt` doesn't return a variable.

Comment: `swapped.charAt()` cannot be used to assign a new character in the string, you might want to rethink how to do this.

Comment: Since `charAt()` is read-only, you can only store the result of it. You have to cast `temp1` to an integer to even use it correctly. `char ch = swapped.charAt((int) temp1);`

Answer (score 3):

You can assign values to variables, not other values. Statements like `5 = 2` or `'a' = 'z'` don't work in Java, and that's why you're getting an error. `swapped.charAt(temp1)` returns some `char` **value** you're trying to overwrite, it's not a reference to a particular position inside the `String` or a variable you can alter (also, mind that Java Strings are immutable so you can't really change them in any way after creation).

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html for information on using `String`, it should have a solution for what you're trying to do.

Your code may even throw IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index argument is negative or not
less than the length of this string. Check the length of each string.

Answer (score 2):

The left side of your assignment cannot receive that value.

Answer (score -1):

Description of [`String#charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29):

> Returns the char value at the specified index

It returns the *value* of the character; assigning values to that returned value in the following lines is the problem:

```
swapped.charAt(temp1) = str.charAt(temp2);
swapped.charAt(temp2) = temp1;
```

Also, `String#charAt(int)` expects an *index* of a character within the String, not the character itself (i.e. `chatAt(temp1)` is incorrect), so your method will not work as expected even if you fix the former problem.

Try the following:

```
String swapped;
if(swap1 > swap2) {
    swap1+=swap2;
    swap2=swap1-swap2;
    swap1-=swap2;
}
if(swap1!=swap2)
    swapped = str.substring(0,swap1) + str.charAt(swap2) + str.substring(swap1, swap2) + str.charAt(swap1) + str.substring(swap2);
```

Comment: They don't "do nothing", they are what's causing the error! There is nothing wrong with the index, apart from possible out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: @kviiri "Does nothing" in the sense that assigning values to values is a pointless endeavor, not in the sense that there is no result (error). The index issue may not throw an Exception, but I'm pointing out that the method will not achieved the desired result because `charAt` would not return the expected character.

Comment: The problem being discussed is the errors, caused by a faulty assignment, not by the indices because the indices are essentially correct unless they go out of bounds.

Comment: @kviiri Regardless of whether it was brought up by OP, it bears mentioning.

Comment: so something that's not causing these particular errors is "why the OP is going to have problems" while the actual source of the error "does nothing"? You're not making much sense.